# Best way to store large data and make reports from them. mongoDb vs elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, bigdata, reporting

We have Contact Center in which there are about 1 million of records are created every days. we use mysql as primary database. Records are about calls time, agents that answer it, call type and ...
Create analytical report from this system is really time consuming (Example: Calculate agents calls for specific month). We need near real time report from our system.
So we decide to store logs and reports in nosql database in improve access time to data.
Which method do you prefer? and why?

1. use mongoDb
2. use elasticsearch as primary database.
3. use big data (Hadoop, spark, ...)
4. others

Comment: We have just insert new data about calls every day. never update, never delete any thing

Answer (score 1):

Lot of people are using elasticsearch plus Kibana to do such things.

I'm doing myself demos on my laptop with more than 1 million records representing people on which I'm building BI real time reports with Kibana.

Disclaimer: I'm working at elastic.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB can offer you much flexibility and is a general purpose database so you can use it for much more than simple text searching/storage. Storing 1 million documents in MongoDB will probably not even require sharding... a simple replica set should suffice. However, give thought to your document structure - and be sure you're not simply migrating tables to collections - that will not likely give you the performance you require. Look at the read/write profile of your application and be careful to not store unbounded arrays. Also, try to summarize where it makes sense so reporting and retrieval performance is good. BTW, you can test this out using MongoDB Atlas - starting for free. I just completed a screencast/blog showing you how to get started: http://blog.mlynn.org/getting-started-with-mongodb-atlas/ Hope this helps.